# How to set different decimal places in same rapidjson document

Tags: formatting, rapidjson

I have made a rapidjson document with all my objects and values using usual  AddMember() method. Now I want to get the string out of that document for publishing to a mqtt broker. But inside that string, some members shall have 2 decimal places, some only one, and others all decimals.
I don't find how to set decimal place for a specific member after the document was fully builded.

I succeeded to do so by building my json document with a writer but this is not what i want to do because this document can't be easily modified:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>     // rapidjson's DOM-style API
#include <rapidjson/prettywriter.h> // for stringify JSON
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>

using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Document doc;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    writer.StartObject();
    writer.Key("member1");
    writer.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(2);
    writer.Double(1.0000001);
    writer.Key("member2");
    writer.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(3);
    writer.Double(3.123456);
    writer.Key("member3");
    writer.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(8);
    writer.Double(2.123456);
    writer.EndObject();
    cout << buffer.GetString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
./decimal
{"member1":1.0,"member2":3.123,"member3":2.123456}
```

Now, this how i build my document:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>     // rapidjson's DOM-style API
#include <rapidjson/prettywriter.h> // for stringify JSON
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>

using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Document doc;
    Document::AllocatorType& allocator = doc.GetAllocator();
    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    doc.SetObject();
    doc.AddMember("member1", 1.0000001, allocator);
    doc.AddMember("member3", 3.123456, allocator);
    doc.AddMember("member2", 2.123456, allocator);
    writer.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(2);
    doc.Accept(writer);

    cout << buffer.GetString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
./decimal
{"member1":1.0,"member2":2.12,"member3":3.12}
```

The SetMaxDecimalPlaces() applies to the whole document this way

I would like to get same output has first code example but using document made from second source code. How can i tell the writer to format each member differently ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm super late to the party, but you can create a second writer with different writing settings:

```
StringBuffer buffer;

Writer<StringBuffer> writer1(buffer); // original writer
Writer<StringBuffer> writer2(buffer); // a new second writer

writer1.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(1);
writer2.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(2);
```

and then use the specific writers to write directly into the buffer instead of using the doc to call the writer:

```
writer.Key("member1");
writer.Double(1.0);

writer2.Key("member2");
writer2.Double(2.12);

writer2.Key("member3");
writer2.Double(3.12);
```

---

Full example:

```
using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    StringBuffer buffer;

    Writer<StringBuffer> writer1(buffer);
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer2(buffer);

    writer1.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(2);
    writer2.SetMaxDecimalPlaces(2);

    writer1.StartObject();

    writer1.Key("member1");
    writer1.Double(1.0);

    writer2.Key("member2");
    writer2.Double(2.12);

    writer2.Key("member3");
    writer2.Double(3.12);

    writer1.EndObject();

    cout << buffer.GetString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```